# Оптимизация в JAVA

Tags: java, оптимизация

Скажите, надо и если надо то как можно оптимизировать этот код? возможно заменить это джойнами из базы, а не этими двух этажными циклами или что лучше почитать об оптимизации в JAVA, чтобы перестать писать этот га*нокод, как говорят мои коллеги. 
Так как на этом этапе, я Trainee/Junior но очень бы хотел улучшить свой скилл в программирование и начать писать хороший код.

```
public List<Place> getPlacesByPlaceTypeId(PlaceTypeForm placeType) {

    List<Place> allPlaces = getAllPlaces();
    List<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();
    for (Place place : allPlaces) {
        if (place.getId() == placeType.getId()) {
            places.add(place);
        }
    }

    return places;
}

public void addPlace(PlaceForm placeForm, MultipartFile multipartFile){

    Place place = new Place();
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeDao.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceTypeId());
    place.setName(placeForm.getName());
    place.setFile(fileService.saveFile(multipartFile, "place"));
    place.getPlaceTypes().add(placeType);
    placeType.getPlaces().add(place);
}

public void deletePlace(PlaceForm placeForm){
    Place place = placeDao.getPlaceById(placeForm.getId());
    List<PlaceType> placeTypes = new ArrayList<PlaceType>(place.getPlaceTypes());
    List<Menu> menus = new ArrayList<Menu>(place.getMenus());
    Iterator<PlaceType> placeTypeList = placeTypes.iterator();
    while(placeTypeList.hasNext()){
        placeTypeList.next().getPlaces().remove(place);
    }
    place.getPlaceTypes().removeAll(placeTypes);
    place.getMenus().removeAll(menus);
    placeDao.deletePlace(place);
}

public void deletePlaceFromPlaceType(PlaceForm placeForm){
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeDao.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceTypeId());
    placeType.getPlaces().remove(placeDao.getPlaceById(placeForm.getId()));
}

public boolean addPlaceToAnyPlaceType(PlaceForm placeForm){
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeDao.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceTypeId());
    List<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>(placeType.getPlaces());
    Iterator<Place> placeList = places.iterator();
    while(placeList.hasNext()){
        if(placeList.next().equals(placeDao.getPlaceById(placeForm.getId()))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    placeType.getPlaces().add(placeDao.getPlaceById(placeForm.getId()));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Так если вы Trainee/Junior, почему бы вашим коллегам вам не помочь? PS. я видимо тоже говнокодер, потому что я ничего принципиально плохого не вижу в вашем коде.

Comment: во во, согласен с @Vartlok, да и что Вы понимаете под оптимизацией? оптимизацию производительности, или же просто сделать код более красивым)

Comment: @ermak0ff оптимизацию производительности. Нужно сделать рефактор этой части кода, чтобы ускорить процесс загрузки. Я так себе подумал, что это скорее всего можно было бы сделать join'ами напрямую из базы, вместо того, чтобы сравнивать айдишки и потом сортировать в зависимости от результата, но существенно ли это что-то изменит? 
А на счет красоты, я свой код в любом виде люблю, он для меня всегда красивый )

Comment: Мне одному этот код напомнил про [Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.de/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы хотите провести рефакторинг кода, а не оптимизацию. В приведенном участке кода оптимизировать нечего, либо это слишком не существенно.

1. Если это класс с набором методов для работы с объектами класса `Place`, то нет необходимости в названии каждого метода об этом упоминать.
2. Также заменим *delete* на *remove* (стандартное имя метода для удаления элемента из коллекции в `Java`).
3. Методу `getPlacesByPlaceTypeId(PlaceTypeForm placeType)` требуется только идентификатор. Зачем передавать весь объект? То же самое касается метода `deletePlace(PlaceTypeForm placeType)` и метода `deletePlaceFromPlaceType(PlaceTypeForm placeType)`.
4. Старайтесь давать более осмысленные имена переменным/методам/классам. Например, если `MultipartFile multipartFile` в методе `addPlace` - это присоединяемый файл к месту с его описанием, то можно назвать аргумент, как `descriptionFile` или `attachedFile`. Тут уже зависит от контекста, которого я не знаю.

Обновленный интерфейс класса:

```
public List<Place> getByTypeId(int typeId);
public void add(PlaceForm form, MultipartFile attachedFile);
public void remove(int formId);
```

5. Почему у вас `PlaceType` (тип места) должен хранить список мест? Это совершенно не его обязанность! Необходимо пересмотреть архитектуру. Тип места - это свойство объекта класса `Place`, которое может принимать значения из допустимых `PlaceType` (если это перечисление). Соответственно получение списка мест по определенному типу - это правильно сформированный запрос к БД и все.
6. Зачем в методе `getPlacesByPlaceTypeId()` получать все места, а затем их фильтровать? А если объектов будет несколько десятков тысяч? Напишите в вашем `DAO` нормальный запрос, который сразу будет возвращать все объекты с определенным идентификатором.
7. Цепочки такого рода `placeType.getPlaces().add(placeDao.getPlaceById(placeForm.getId()));` трудно читать и отлаживать (почитайте, например, [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103985/method-chaining-why-is-it-a-good-practice-or-not), где обсуждается этот вопрос).

Можно продолжать и дальше, но думаю и этого достаточно.

> а не этими двух этажными циклами или что лучше почитать об оптимизации
>   в JAVA, чтобы перестать писать этот га*нокод, как говорят мои коллеги.

Не знаю при чем здесь оптимизация, либо вы не правильно поняли слова коллег. Прочитайте про принципы проектирования, почитайте "Совершенный код" Стива Макконелла.

Comment: `Почему у вас PlaceType (тип места) должен хранить список мест?`
так как здесь связь ManyToMany, я посчитал, что это было бы правильным оформлением,  но  я учту и пересмотрю архитектуру.

Answer (score 3):

Такой код неудобно поддерживать/отлаживать.

Возьмем данную строчку кода:

```
public void deletePlaceFromPlaceType(PlaceForm placeForm){
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeDao.getPlaceTypeById(placeForm.getPlaceTypeId());
    placeType.getPlaces().remove(placeDao.getPlaceById(placeForm.getId()));
}
```

Тут: `placeForm.getPlaceTypeId()` вы можете словить NPE, если каким то образом на входе функции будет `null`, по этому имеет смысл добавить проверку, и если null это не нормальное поведение, то отреагировать соответствующе, например кинуть исключение с нормальным описанием проблемы.

Ваши DAO вряд ли могут быть равными `null`, по этому чекать их нет смысла.

Реультат вызова `placeForm.getPlaceTypeId()` лучше вынести в отдельную переменную. Во время отладки удобнее будет посмотреть значение переменной, до того, как оно попадет в DAO. Не бойтесь заводить новые переменные, компилятор умеет оптимизировать подобное.

`placeType.getPlaces()` так же стоит вынести в отдельную переменную, все так же ради удобной отладки. Если  `getPlaces()` может вернуть `null`, то необходимо добавить проверку.

Ну и так далее со всем кодом. Сейчас это просто стенка непонятного и не читабельного кода. Правильный же код должен читаться как текст.

Что касается оптимизации, то займитесь написанием более оптимальных обращений к базе, пользуйтесь индексами. Особо требовательные запросы пишите на SQL'e.

Comment: разве это не сделает код еще более нагруженным и стенку еще более громоздкой?

Comment: @Khodan.D. нет, современные компиляторы очень продвинулись в вопросах оптимизации. Визуально кода станет больше, но его будет гораздо проще отлаживать. Сейчас же ваш код отлаживать будет не удобно.

Comment: а насколько правильным будет заменить циклы джойнами из базы ? Это сделает код проще и лучше или ничего не изменит?

Comment: @Khodan.D. сделает это проще запрос или нет, вы можете узнать построив `план запроса`